# Using VB6 DLL in C# - only see "get_" methods but not equivalent properties

Tags: .net, vb6, interop

I have a VB6 DLL with class `C` having property `P`.

I add this DLL to a C# project as a reference. I am able to declare an object of type `C` but intellisense will only show the following as valid:

`C.get_P()`

and there is no `C.P` which is unexpected. If I attempt to use that syntax, I'll get errors like

> 'C' does not contain a definition for 'P' and no extension method 'P'
>   ... could be found...

The type of `P` is a class. Properties of `C` which are more elementary types (such as Boolean) do not seem to have this problem.

Now, when this occurs, it seems to be spontaneous; places where `C.P` used to be valid suddenly will no longer do so. I can't figure out what leads to this, or how to correct it.

Comment: It is not unusual, VB6 permits declaring indexed properties.  You did not show an example of one, but the shoe fits.  They have no mapping to C#, it has only one indexed property (this[]).  So as a workaround, the type library importer turns the property into a method with `get_` prefixed to the property name.  Unless you use the .NET 4 version of tlbimp.exe and use C# v4 or higher.  Having to use the method is not the end of the world.  Do consider updating your VS version, there is a lot more COM goodness in VS2010 and up.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant for your thoughtful suggestion. I think however the problem was that the VB6 DLL was somehow registered incompletely. regsvr32 reported no problems, but a COM dependency of the DLL was missing which I think prevented it from being FULLY registered. I may add this as an answer except that it seems strange and flaky and I'm unsure of precisely why things went wrong.